# what does "$env:SECRET_KEY = "<mysecretkey>" command command means?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I am following the saleor docs and came across `"$env:SECRET_KEY = "<mysecretkey>"`
I tried this in my windows 10 command prompt but it doesn't work and gives me the following error- The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

so what's that command used for and why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this in my windows 10 command prompt but it doesn't work

The command you found in the tutorial was for *PowerShell*, not Command Prompt.

Windows 10 comes with two command interpreters: Cmd (the traditional "Command Prompt") and PowerShell. They have similar basic commands but very different syntax, with PowerShell trying to improve on Cmd's kludges dating from MS-DOS era. You'll find both in the Start Menu.

In Cmd (Command Prompt), you would set the same environment variable like this:

```
set SECRET_KEY=<mysecretkey>
```

or like this:

```
set "SECRET_KEY=<mysecretkey>"
```

Note: In Cmd, quoting just the value won't actually work the way you expect: the quotes will end up stored as *part of the value.* (You can see the result by running just `set SECRET_KEY` or `set SECR`.)

Comment: i am really feeling stupid that i didn't tried the command in powershell. i searched in google but couldn't find any reference to that powershell and cmd issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Windows 10

Just type this then it works for me:

```
setx SECRET_KEY "<your secret key>"
```

Then after that it should say: SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

Comment: It works but it does a different thing. OP's command sets the variable immediately and temporarily. Yours sets it permanently, but only on next reboot.